# how do I create a regex for this in urls.py?

Tags: python, django, regex, django-rest-framework

I want to create a regex that matches urls like this

```
filmslist?name=allaboutmymother?director=pedroalmodovar
```

in urlpatterns, I've put this:

```
path('api/filmslist\?name=?P<name>(.*)\?director=?P<director>(.*)', views.filmslist)
```

but it doesn't match.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `api/filmslist` should be enough, everything from `?` onwards is a querystring (GET parameters)

Comment: You have your named capture groups wrong, it is `(?P<some_cool_name>...)`. That said, it should be `filmslist\?name=(?P<name>.*)\?director=(?P<director>.*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/eLfjsX/1

Comment: The *qyerystring* is not part of the path. You will need to parse this in the view itself.

Comment: Are there really two `?`s in the URL?

Answer (score 3):

Everything after the first `?` in a url is a querystring and is not involved in the pattern matching. So if your url is like `filmslist?name=allaboutmymother?director=pedroalmodovar` then your url pattern should be like:

```
path('api/filmslist', views.filmslist)
```

Now to get those parameters in your view you can do something like:

```
def filmslist(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    director = request.GET.get('director')
    ...
```

Also as noted by [@Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67304614/how-do-i-create-a-regex-for-this-in-urls-py/67304721#comment118965220_67304614) in their comment their should only be **one** `?` in a url and the parameters need to be separated by an `&` so your url should be `filmslist?name=allaboutmymother&director=pedroalmodovar`

Answer (score 2):

The [*qyery string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is not part of the path. You will need to parse this in the view itself. In the view you can access parameters with `request.GET` which is a dictionary-like structure, so:

```
path('api/filmslist/', views.filmslist)
```

in the view you can then inspect the values with:

```
def filmslist(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    director = request.GET.get('director')
    # …
```

If the parameter is not passed in the queryset, the corresponding `name` or `director` will be `None`.